# Is it safe to reboot my phone?

Tags: 7.5, micro-sd

I have a 1st gen Samsung Focus running 7.5. About a month ago something got corrupted and I had to factory reset, which I'd never done having it for two years. At the time I decided to insert a MicroSD card I had and it integrated without problem and I had additional storage.

Except... A couple weeks ago, I wanted to swap out my nearly depleted battery for a fresh one I've always kept on hand just in case, but upon restarting, I got an error that the SD card was "missing or corrupt" and I was forced to reset my phone again. Again I included the card and it worked, now with the understanding I can no longer remove the battery.

A couple days later, I attempted to charge with a faulty cable, the battery depleted, and I was faced with the same scenario. Again I had to reset the phone (with the card) and install all my apps and games.

Not removing or depleting the battery I can live with if it means I have the additional storage. However, I'm now left wondering if I can reboot my phone or if turning it off means the card is wiped again and I'll have to reset once more.

I'm upgrading to a WP8 device soon, so it's not life or death, but neither am I anxious to reinstall everything a fourth time. So I'm wondering if anyone has any experience or insight into this scenario.

**Edit:**

According to responses to [this article](http://www.intomobile.com/2010/11/09/samsung-focus-plagued-with-microsd-card-issues/), a class 4 card should work without issue. To my knowledge (because I can't take it out to check) I'm using a class 2, which probably explains the wonkiness. I'm not up on exactly what MicroSD classes mean, but apparently my card needs constant power, behaving more like volatile RAM. So I'm still wondering if rebooting completely de-powers the phone, or if the card will still receive power through the reboot process.

Answer (score 4):

I heard that the Samsung Focus SD card is most misunderstanding feature of all Windows Phone phones.

It was supposed to be used only for OEM and carriers do offer more room for games and files to the user. But without any possibility to remove or even use the SD card in another device.

As far as I know when you insert the SD card in the phone you need to hard reset it. It will erase de SD card and integrate with the internal memory. I never heard problems related with what you are saying.

I have a friend with the same phone and he said removed and inserted the card many times trying using it in the PC without success but always using in the phone again with no problems.

It should not corrupt the SD card if you are  rebooting your phone, but it should not corrupt with you remove the battery too.

Comment: I don't think the card really needs power always. Because the SD card looses its meaning in that way.